# To know the state of the branch rebase

Tags: git

As the title says,
is there a way to know the state of your branch rebase ?

In others words, when you issue:

```
git rebase branch1
```

you do not know if it is going to take 3 minutes :) or 3 hours :(

Is there a way to know the number of conflicts you have to fix when rebasing ?
(so you could decide if it is more convinient just to merge)

Thanks

Comment: Put simply, no. Something like `git rev-list --right-only HEAD...branch1 | wc -l` will give you an idea of how many commits you're going to have to rebase, but there's no way to tell how many conflicts you're going to fix until you start.

Comment: Or you could just start your rebase, see how bad it looks and run away with `--abort`, no ? Plus rebase vs. rebase shouldn't depend on the size of you diff and/or number of conflicts but rather how you want to manage your branching and commit history.

Comment: Agree with @cmbuckley.. I know this doesn't answer your question but this might help some to see which files have a rebase conflict > git diff --name-only --diff-filter=U

Comment: `--interactive` option of the git rebase will give a quick glimpse on what will be rebased, and you have an option to reconsider.

Comment: `--interactive` is a good route if you're confident about aborting it, otherwise `git log --oneline HEAD...branch1` will give you the same information.